# Why my code are retrieving ads between each object that are being retrieved?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to retrieve the ads in index number 3. But my code is retrieving ads between each object that is retrieved by firebase. Could something show me my error?

--- Here is My RecyclerView---

```
private static final int ads = 0, content = 1, book = 2;

private Context mContext;
private List<Object> mDataset;

// View Holder for data item
public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView views_discover, titleofthecontent;
    Context ctx;
    Button gotoFeed_discover;
    ImageView img_discover;
    View postPosted;

    DataViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.ctx = ctx;
        postPosted = itemView;

        views_discover = view.findViewById(R.id.views_discover);
        gotoFeed_discover = view.findViewById(R.id.gotofeed_discover);
        titleofthecontent = view.findViewById(R.id.title_discover);
        img_discover = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_discover);
    }

    public void setDateInDiscover( final Context ctx, final Feed_modell modell){

        String Name = modell.getName2();
        String Title = modell.getTitle();
        String Views = modell.getViews();
        String thumbnail = modell.getThumbnail();

        Picasso.get().load(thumbnail).error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled).into(img_discover);
        titleofthecontent.setText(Title);
        views_discover.setText(Name);

        postPosted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), video.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", modell.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("name2", modell.getName2());
                intent.putExtra("link", modell.getLink());
                intent.putExtra("path", modell.getPath());
                intent.putExtra("UID", modell.getUID());
                intent.putExtra("videokey", modell.getVideokey());
                intent.putExtra("views", modell.getViews());
                intent.putExtra("feedkey", modell.getFeedkey());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        gotoFeed_discover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), feed_pushmycreator.class);
                intent.putExtra("feedkey", modell.getFeedkey());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}

// View Holder for Admob Native Express Ad Unit
public class BannerAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private AdRequest adRequest;
    private AdView adView;

    BannerAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        adView = view.findViewById(R.id.banner300x250id);
    }

    public void setAds(final Context ctx, final all_modell ads){

        MobileAds.initialize(ctx.getApplicationContext(), ads.getAdsId()); // "standard app ID to test: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"
        // adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Button videosbtn, listiclesbtn, bookbtn;

    HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        videosbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.Videosdh);
        listiclesbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.Listiclesdh);
        bookbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.Booksdh);
    }

    public void setHeaderButtons(Discover_modell discover_modell){

        String videosdm = discover_modell.getVideosDm();
        String bookdm = discover_modell.getBooksDm();
        String listicedm = discover_modell.getListiclesDm();

        videosbtn.setText(videosdm);
        listiclesbtn.setText(listicedm);
        bookbtn.setText(bookdm);
    }
}

public static class viewHolderbook extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    static TextView booktitle, bookautor;
    public static Button bookimg;
    public static View postPosted;
    Context ctx;

    public viewHolderbook(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.ctx = ctx;
        postPosted = itemView;

        booktitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_discover);
        bookimg = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gotofeed_discover);

    }

    public void setBook(final Book book){

        String Name = book.getBookautor();
        String Title = book.getBooktitle();

        booktitle.setText(Title);
    }
}

// Constructor for Adapter
public AdmobRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Object> dataset) {

    this.mContext = context;
    this.mDataset = dataset;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    int layout = 0;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    // Identify viewType returned by getItemViewType(...)
    // and return ViewHolder Accordingly
    switch (viewType){
        case content:
            layout= R.layout.discover_row;
            View contentView = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder=new DataViewHolder(contentView);
            break;

        case book:
            layout=R.layout.discover_row;
            View bookview = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder=new viewHolderbook(bookview);
            break;

        case ads:
            layout=R.layout.banner300x250;
            View header = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder=new BannerAdViewHolder(header);
            break;

        default:
            viewHolder=null;
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int viewType=holder.getItemViewType();
    switch (viewType){
        case content:

            Feed_modell call = (Feed_modell ) mDataset.get(position);
            ((DataViewHolder)holder).setDateInDiscover(mContext, call);
            break;

        case book:

            Book book = (Book) mDataset.get(position);
            ((viewHolderbook)holder).setBook(book);
            break;

        case ads:

            all_modell hheaderr = (all_modell) mDataset.get(3);
            ((BannerAdViewHolder)holder).setAds(mContext, hheaderr);
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (mDataset.get(position) instanceof Feed_modell) {

        return content;

    } else if (mDataset.get(position) instanceof Book) {
        return book;

    } else if (mDataset.get(3) instanceof all_modell) {
        return ads;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

--- My Activity ---

```
    mDataSet.clear();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("feedPosts");

    Query queryFeed = databaseReference;
    childEventListener = queryFeed.limitToFirst(33).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            for (DataSnapshot value : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                Feed_modell object = value.getValue(Feed_modell.class);


                // getting some data from this child to add to another array
                mDataSet.add(object);
                mDataSet.add(new all_modell("ca-app-pub3940256099942544~3347511713"));

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    //databaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

}
```

I don't know why but isn't working as I want. For each content are being shown ads, what I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here in `viewHolderbook`:

```
static TextView booktitle, bookautor;
public static Button bookimg;
public static View postPosted;
```

You have defined these variables as `static`. That means that they are **class variables** and not **instance variables** and they exist only once. Remove the `static` keywords.

---

**Second problem**

Here is the second problem, in `getItemViewType()`:

```
} else if (mDataset.get(3) instanceof all_modell) {
    return ads;
}
```

Obviously if `mDataset.get(3)` is an instance of `all_modell`, then this will return `ads`, no matter what the value of `position` is.

Comment: I just changed in my code what you said and I tested it. Unfortunatly didn't work. Still the same.